# How to input a char or a string without hitting the return key

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm learning Objective C using Foundation and printing to the console. I would like to know (and how) if it is possible to input a char or string and it print out automatically without hitting the return key (or any key). Obviously the simple code below still requires the return key to be hit. I am aware this code is mixed between C & objC but I've been trying out differnet ideas. I am also trying to do this without using Ncurses. Thanks in advance.

char input [1];

```
NSLog(@"enter key:");

fgets(input, 1, stdin);

NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:input];

NSLog(@"Input = %s",input);
```

Ive just found a good answer as follows:
 // Set terminal to raw mode 
    system("stty raw");

```
// Wait for single character 
char input = getchar(); 

// Echo input:


// Reset terminal to normal "cooked" mode 
system("stty cooked"); 

// And we're out of here 

NSLog(@"INPUT = %c",input);
```

Comment: 8 questions asked, none accepted and zero votes cast -- people might wonder why they should prioritize their valuable time on you.

Comment: @KerrekSB - for the searchers. People wanting answers to those same questions who will now find them. Might even give you upvotes if that's what you're after. Not everyone participates the same way.

Comment: You know that your solution with `system()` is starting a complete shell in a subprocess that does, in this case, pretty much the same as `cfmakeraw()` mentioned in my reply, right? Additionally, the manual for `stty` mentions the tty flags the raw option sets, so why not just set them with `tcsetattr`? I get the feeling you're ignoring the answers you get, on purpose.

Comment: @KerrekSB lighten up a little bit - you seem so bitter and sad. My post clearly states Im new to objective C and I have a genuine question. To date this site has been really helpful by what seems like good people - don't let it down.

Comment: @KateGregory - Im not interested with upVotes. I simply found an answer and I thought it might help others reading this post.

Comment: @pete as the original asker, one way to help others is to upvote good answers (on your questions or on others) and to accept answers that you can attest helped you the most. I was just telling Kerrek that you doing so is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual for `tcsetattr` and `tcgetattr`. Look for the flags `ICANON` and `IECHO`, and check out the part about `cfmakeraw`. The documentation `console_ioctl(4)` and `tty_ioctl(4)` may be of further interest, for example to determine the size of the tty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I need some time to play around this.

Comment: and, did you come up with a solution? How did the tests go?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://pwilson.net/sample.html and search for kbhit.c . That function should work for you, though it's not been tested with Objective C.